# Setting context variable in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Here is the code I am working with:

```
class FeedView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = "feed/feed_list.html"
    model = Feed


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(FeedView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response


    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(FeedView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["feeds"] = Feed.objects.all()
        context["new_feed_form"] = FeedFormSet(queryset = Feed.objects.none())
        context["commentform"] = CommentForm()

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        formset = FeedFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if formset.is_valid():
            forms = formset.save(commit=False) 
            for form in forms:
                form.name = self.request.user

                form.save()

            return redirect("feeds")
        else:
            # THIS WAY 

            context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

            # OR THIS WAY
            # context = {
            #   'feeds' : Feed.objects.all(),
            # }

            # context["new_feed_form"] = formset
            return render(request, self.template_name , context)
```

Inside the `Post` method, when the form is invalid, setting `context` variable by `context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)` gives me the error `'FeedView' object has no attribute 'object_list'`. However setting them all again (shown below 'OR THIS WAY' in the code) works fine. How do I fix the error while setting the `context` variable by `context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)` ?

Comment: The error happens because `ListView` expects certain instance variables (like `object_list`) to be set. You shouldn't really be using the `ListView` to handle that `POST` request at all - it would be cleaner to make a separate `FormView` that handles it. You're also not using the benefits that a `ListView` provides because you're manually adding your own queryset to the context instead of using the one generated by the view.

Comment: you mean to say that i should create a separate view for that handles the post data right ? and for that, i will be requiring to define url for that view in the `urls.py` file and in the template , i should do `<form action = '{% url "my_new_view" %}' `. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes. I think that will be much cleaner and more maintainable as you are separating the logic. You also should look at what `ListView` provides as you are currently manually duplicating some of what it already does for you in terms of generating the queryset of list items.